# How to use Ruby on Rails users controller via Unity (C#) to sign up a new user?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine

I have a user controller created using the hartl tutorial that signs up new users via form with email and password inputs. This is working properly. I am attempting to send an HttpWebRequest from the Unity editor player to my server in order to sign up a new user from a password string created within Unity. I have provided the error response and the code relevant to the attempt below.

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) (at ><4b9f316768174388be8ae5baf2e6cc02>:0)
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () (at <4b9f316768174388be8ae5baf2e6cc02>:0)
>   UnityStandardAssets.Characters.RigidbodyFirstPersonController.RigidbodyFirstPer>sonController.resetScene3 () (at >Assets/Scripts/RigidbodyFirstPersonController.cs:463)

## HttpWebRequest Code from RigidbodyFirstPer>sonController.resetScene3 ():

```
public static string _url = "https://immense-castle-53592.herokuapp.com/signup";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers ["action"] = "/users";
    request.Headers ["class"] = "new_user";
    request.Headers ["id"] = "new_user";
    request.Headers ["utf8"] = "&#x2713;";
    request.Headers ["authenticity_token"] = "NNb6+J/j46LcrgYUC60wQ2titMuJQ5lLqyAbnbAUkdo=";
    request.Headers ["user_email"] = "jakebrantley44@gmail.com";
    request.Headers ["user_password"] = passwordUnity;

        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Debug.Log("Publish Response: " + (int)response.StatusCode + ", " + response.StatusDescription);
            if((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                //SetEnvironmentVersion(version);
            }
        }
```

### Ruby on Rails Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    puts params[:password]
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to your vault!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

#### Routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/demo',    to: 'static_pages#demo'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
  post '/', to: 'users#create'
  get '/show', to: 'users#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
```

Update: New code from attempt utilizing Stream.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_url);

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";

    // Add dictionary strings
    headers["action"] = "/users";
    headers["class"] = "new_user";
    headers["id"] = "new_user";
    headers["utf8"] = "&#x2713;";
    headers["authenticity_token"] = "NNb6+J/j46LcrgYUC60wQ2titMuJQ5lLqyAbnbAUkdo=";
    headers["user_email"] = "jakebrantley44@gmail.com";
    headers["user_password"] = passwordUnity;

    byte[] headersByte = UnityWebRequest.SerializeSimpleForm(headers);
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = headersByte.Length;
    Debug.Log( headersByte );
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write (headersByte, 0, headersByte.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            //Read the content
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            Debug.Log(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
            Debug.Log("Publish Response: " + (int)response.StatusCode + ", " + response.StatusDescription);

            if((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you missing the request body?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you be more specific? I wrote the request according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Comment: I don't see Step 7: "dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); "

Comment: It is my understanding that with HttpWebRequest the data may be transferred via headers or byte[]. I get the same error when attempting to send a byte[].

Comment: @LeoBartkus I have updated the post showing an attempt using dataStream. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

1. Changed method of post from `Http.Web.Request` to `UnityWebRequest`. `Http.Web.Request` headers aren't intended to be used for passing parameters.
2. Changed Ruby/Rails **users_controller.rb** `user_params` function to the following. The controller needed to be set to `.fetch` the parameter values:

```
def user_params
    puts "user_params runs"
    unless params["user"].blank?
        puts "main state user_params"
        params.fetch(:user, {:email => params[:EMAIL], :password => params[:PASSWORD]}).permit(:email, :password)
    end
    puts "unless state in user_params"
    params.fetch(:user, {"email"=>params[:EMAIL], "password"=>params[:PASSWORD]}).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The ruby code is looking for the params `:email` and `:password`, but in the client side, you are adding `user_email` and `user_password` to the header instead.

Also based on the updated code, I think you should put

```
if((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
{

}
```

before `response.Close();`.

Comment: When I create a new user via the site (not Unity), this is what gets submitted to the server: 2018-10-17T20:20:41.783434+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-10-17T20:20:41.783315 #11]  INFO -- : [b014b248-cbce-4612-9edc-b88427b6d03f]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/AfTAk1pl2kMFlrK4xN6e0XCtrw+kh6QSp+H0gT/LVtgtKfc+g8XmGrpjEd+zjKzhlGQoIg4YJiAKseUkh+HpA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"jakebrantley104@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}

Comment: So essentially I need to know how to properly define the user variable in C# from Unity. "user"=>{"email"=>"jakebrantley104@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"} isn't proper C# syntax and wouldn't include the correct PW anyway. Any idea?

Comment: I just checked [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SerializeSimpleForm.html). It seems that this is used for GET requests as it forms the key-value with key=value&key2=value2.

Your signup is a POST so you need a body for that. I think using Stream is the right way to do it but you just have to know how to form it, but I can't help you with that as I am not that familiar with it.

Comment: What we use for registration in Unity is UnityWebRequest itself.
`var request = new UnityWebRequest (url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);` then add the parameters to the body using `request .uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw (encodedBody);`. where encoded body is the encoded body originally a string in JSON format

Comment: I attempted UnityWebRequest. Problem is UnityWebRequest doesn't work form the editor, so I would need everything to be perfect on the first go before embedding it into my rails app. Debugging would be a nightmare if I had to do that over and over again. Would be very convenient to get it to work via HTTPWebRequest.